# Possible source of a 120Hz noise on ADC?

Tags: adc, noise, mains, interference

I have a photodiode connected to an ADC through a current to voltage converter (opa376 opamp).

I'm getting this 120Hz noise/interference. I would expect 60Hz main noise and maybe some 2nd harmonic at 120Hz but not 120Hz Only.

What could be the source of this signal?

[image: 16bit, Sample rate ~15kHz.] 
 16bit, Sample rate ~15kHz.

[image: circuit]

Comment: Fluorescent lights flicker at 120 Hz.

Comment: This one was during the day. What's interesting are the sharp transitions.

Comment: Are you certain your system (i.e. op-amp + photo-diode) is stable? The sharp transitions are fishy. Also, is your ADC connected single-ended or differential?

Comment: @DanielV I'm not sure if it's stable. I should be but I did not have a way to check. It's single ended.

Comment: If your circuit is crappy then yes you could see 120 Hz from bad PSRR. I don't see your circuit so no more speculation!

Comment: @DanielV  could an instability in opamp or ldo look like this?

Comment: If the op-amp is marginally stable you could get the waveform you show. It could also be the VREF of the ADC, PSRR of the op-amp, etc. etc. Maybe add some more descriptions as to some debug steps you have done and we could chime in.

Comment: It's powered from an USB of a laptop running on a battery. I'm using low noise ldo LP5907 which powers opamp and analog section of the MCU. Using data sheet recommended decoupling caps and a solid analog ground plane.

Comment: I've attached the amp part.

Comment: Can you measure the output of the opamp on a scope? If the issue isn't there it would point to the ADC

Comment: @DanielV Its was interference from an LCD TV. Optical

Comment: Yep. That would do it. Many LCD displays flicker at 120 Hz (for a similar reason as pointed out by @Kevin Reid) and there is a chance even the backlight flickers at the same rate

Comment: You should take the part that you put in "**EDIT:**" and post it as an answer instead, and accept it. That way people can see the question is settled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a LCD tv with LED backlight about 2m away.

It's was optical.

Answer (score 4):

(This is mainly expanding on Nick Alexeev's comment — I can't say whether there are *other* effects to consider.)

You will see this unless you shield your photodiode from all ambient light or you take it outdoors, because **almost any line-powered electric light source will flicker at 120 Hz** insofar as it flickers at all.

The flicker is 120 Hz rather than 60 Hz for the same reason the output of a bridge rectifier has a frequency of 120 Hz: the processes along the way from the AC waveform to the emitted light don't care about the sign of the current.

The exception to this would be if you used a low-quality LED lamp that connected a single series string of LEDs across the line — this would effectively be a half-wave rectifier and therefore flicker at 60 Hz. But good LED lamps will have a full-wave rectifier, antiparallel LEDs, or a more elaborate power supply.

Incandescent lamps are electrically resistors so the heat and therefore the light varies with the square of the current, and the square of a sine has twice the frequency (but of course, the thermal mass acts as a filter, so you can't usually notice the flicker).

In fluorescent lamps, the behavior depends on the type of ballast in use. Old-fashioned “magnetic” ballasts pass line AC to the bulb and therefore the arc will flicker at 120 Hz (since, again, it lights up the same no matter which direction the current is flowing) while electronic ballasts synthesize higher frequencies, much like switch-mode power supplies (but still might show 120 Hz variations since they are still influenced by the line voltage).

Comment: This makes sense. But the problem is that I checked that I had no artificial light. Anyway the pattern is the same, with natural or artificial light (without light it's zero because it's not biased)

Answer (score 1):

Probably power supply ripple (if a linear supply) or magnetic coupling. If the former, try decoupling the PD bias supply with a resistor and BFC or a capacitance multiplier.

Actually, from the shape I have a feeling there might be a power supply issue involved- either bad layout with the grounding of something else. If ther is a full-wave 60Hz bridge on a transformer secondary put 10n ceramic caps across each of the four diodes.

Comment: It's USB powered. From a laptop on a battery. No connection to mains.

Comment: What equipment is near by?  Do you have all signals over ground plane with proper return routes without jumping layers?

Comment: it was interference from a TV across the room.

Comment: Great! Was it light or electrical interference?